# Double slashes at the beginning of a URL?

Tags: javascript, css, url, google-chrome-extension, font-face

I'm currently working on a chrome extension that allows me to to download the fonts files that have been used on a webpage.

As I was parsing the fonts for [this site](https://nonny.beer/?ref=maxibestof.one) I ran into a strange edge case for one of the font URLs.

For the font `Freddy` the `@font-face` rule looks like this:

```
@font-face {
font-family: 'Freddy';
src: url("//cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0548/8708/8184/t/24/assets/freddy_regular_2-webfont.woff?v=147712666987587936441646682936") format("woff") , 
  url("//cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0548/8708/8184/t/24/assets/Freddy_Regular_2.ttf?v=64870238297763773461646682938") format("truetype") , 
  url("//cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0548/8708/8184/t/24/assets/freddy_regular_2-webfont.woff2?v=66678714148373221751646682937") format("woff2"); /* Safari, Android, iOS */}
```

This broke my script because the double slash makes it an invalid URL (i.e. if I type it into the browser as is it will give me an error).

So I was wondering — what's the purpose of the double slashes at the beginning of this URL? How does this actually retrieve the font if it seems to be an invalid URL?

Comment: FYI ... `/` is NOT a backslash

Answer (score 6):

When referencing content on another domain, starting a URL with two slashes instead of the `http` or `https` protocol tells the browser to request the URL's content using the same protocol as the source page (to prevent [mixed content](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Mixed_content)).

These URLs are not meant to be typed into an address bar, which is why they appear to be an invalid URL when you try navigating directly to it.

Comment: Got it this makes sense. Do you mind extrapolating on why this double slash is being used (i.e. which problem is it trying to solve)? I went through the "mixed content" page you linked, but I still don't fully understand.

Comment: @bugsyb It was a more common problem 10+ years ago before HTTPS was as ubiquitous as it is today. Using your font TTFs as an example, if they were embedded with `http://cdn...` on a HTTPS page, they would be blocked as mixed content (which prevents HTTP resources from loading on a HTTPS page). Using double slashes is a safe way to ensure content always matches the page. That said, I don't think there's a downside nowadays to always using `https://` for content across the board.